# A/B testing in Sitecore - null datasource error in Glass Mapper

Tags: sitecore, ab-testing, glass-mapper

I have a problem with Sitecore and Glass Mapper, we are using Glass Mapper in our project and all works fine, but when trying to set an A/B testing I got an exception about `null` datasource. The strange thing is that if I check the "Test the Component" window I can see that the Test Content Item field shows the wrong content item (Home):

[image]

What am I missing, could you please advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it is a known issue in the MvcContext in GlassMapper v5.6.162 and earlier.
As per a Slack comment by Neil Shack:-

> the issue relates to the following line
> https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/develop/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc/Web/Mvc/IMvcContext.cs#L173
>
> for normal datasource items
> RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.DataSource returns a guid
> such as {0A275E4A-98DF-4CB3-8A7E-948F53010AE3}, but for A/B
> datasources it returns a string such as
> sitecore://{0A275E4A-98DF-4CB3-8A7E-948F53010AE3}?lang=en&ver=0 which
> causes line 176 to return null

A fix has been submitted as a pull request and should be fixed in a newer version soon.
https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/pull/423

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean for your feedback!